# In VS-2010, how to prevent Toolbox from covering up the current window?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm used to VS-2008, with "MDI" IDE, aka "Overlapping Windows".  This doesn't seem to be an option in VS-2010, so now when I have, say Form1 open, and click the toolbox...it slides over and totally obscures Form1.

So...a great solution would be telling me if there's a way to get vs2010 to allow the MDI interface.

Otherwise, how can I get the toolbox to slide and also slide the set of tabbed windows over so I can see what I'm dragging a control onto?
Thanks,
--Jim

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried pinning the toolbox? There should be a pin icon on the top of the toolbox. If you click it, the toolbox will stay on the screen, but it will resize the Form1 window to make room for the toolbox window.